# Fourier transform of partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How would I find the Fourier Transform of the pde
$$
u_t = u_{xx} + \alpha\cdot u_x,\quad\alpha > 0\,?
$$
I know the definition of the Fourier transform, but I'm not sure how to use it in the context of partial differential equations.

Comment: Please format your questions using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ is a "nice" function (i.e. $f\in H^1$ or $f\in C^1$ with $f(\pm\infty) = 0$) the Fourier transform of its derivative is by partial integration
$$
\widehat{f'}(\omega) = \int f'(x)e^{-2\pi ix\omega}\,dx = 2\pi i\omega\int f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\omega}\,dx = 2\pi i\omega\cdot\hat f(\omega).
$$
So if $U(\omega,t)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$ with respect to $x$, applying the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ to $u_t = u_{xx} + \alpha u_x$ gives
$$
U_t = -4\pi^2\omega^2 U + 2\pi i\omega\alpha U = (-2\pi + i\alpha\omega)2\pi U.
$$

Comment: Sometimes the Fourier transform is denoted as $$ U(\omega,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R} e^{-i\omega x}f(x) $$ then the constants aren't needed. Also, you're missing factors of $\omega$ in the last equation.

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for pointing me to the missing $\omega$'s. I edited.

Answer (score -1):

Just ignore $t$ and apply the transform as usual, you'll get something like

$$ U_t = -\omega^2 U + i\alpha \omega U $$

where $U(\omega,t)$ is the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$, given by

$$ U(\omega,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R} u(x,t) e^{-i\omega x}dx $$

Some constants may apply, depending on your definition of the Fourier transform.

Comment: You mean the Fourier transform with respect to $x$...

Comment: @amsmath That's the default assumption, yes. The Laplace transform is applied with respect to $t$

Comment: So treat it as if it was =+? @Dylan

Comment: @ISA-ISA Any operation involving $t$ isn't affected by the transform.

Comment: @Dylan You should write it in your answer. As it is there now, it's not quite correct.

Comment: @amsmath I disagree. In nearly every context involving PDEs, the Fourier transform is applied with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Dylan You shouldn't care about this but about understandability. And you wrote it's "the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$", which is definitely wrong. "The Fourier tranform of $u(x,t)$" is with respect to $(x,t)$, which is also usual terminology.

Comment: @amsmath I wrote "$U(\omega,t)$ is the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$", so you can infer it's with respect to $x$. If you want to be pedantic, that's fine, but don't deliberately misrepresent my answer to make it seem incorrect.

Comment: @Dylan Your last statement is wrong because I really had to guess what you mean. And no, I did not downvote you. But I'm gonna do it now. Also because the constants are missing. Important is a minus in front of the second term.

Comment: @amsmath As I said, the constants and sign all depend on which definition of the transform you use, of which there are several. This wasn't meant to be a complete answer, so I skipped over a few details to get the point across. You had to guess, but you did understand what I meant, so what's really the problem?

Comment: @Dylan I agree with amsmath. It's ambigous. And the minus does not depend on the definition of FT.

Comment: I will concede on the minus sign.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I think the minus sign should be before the first summand. So I was wrong at first.

Comment: I give you an upvote because there’s nothing wrong. But when I write an answer involving fourier transformation, then I would show the readers my used convention. I saw your convention in the comment, it’s better in the answer.